# Calculate the shortest distance between a point on a route and another point

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I'm building a navigation application and need to calculate the shortest distance between a point on a walking route and a point of interest, e.g. a cathedral.

Imagine someone travelling a route from point A to C (highlighted in red below), via point B. I need to calculate the shortest possible distance between a point on that route to point D. All distances / lengths of the triangles are known (e.g. A to B might be 10, B to D might be 4).

I need to find k and j (wherever they are located between their respective points) - I can compare them later to see which is shorter and drop the longer distance. In reality, A, B, C and D are GPS coordinates.

Any help is much appreciated - many thanks.

[image]
EDIT: updated diagram --> Need to find (Kx, Ky), (Jx, Jy), where K and J are the shortest distance along their respective routes to D.

Comment: The shortest distance between a line and a point is the perpendicular to that line from the point

Comment: I need to find a point K (located somewhere between A and B) where the distance to B is shortest. The same for point J (located somewhere between B and C) where the distance to B is shortest. Perhaps I've overcomplicated it, since the equation is probably the same for both triangles?

Comment: distance formula? $D=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}^2$

Comment: No "route from point A to C" is "highlighted in red below". ​ ​

Comment: You'd do A to B in the distance formula, and then B to C in the distance formula and add the two.

Comment: Sorry, the route goes from A to C, via B. I don't care about A-C directly, although if it helps, I know that distance.

Comment: I need to know the actual coordinate of K / J, I can calculate the distance (k--> D and j-->D). Sorry, should have been clearer.

Comment: Based on what @N.S.JOHN said, If I split the triangle A-B-D into two right-angled triangles A-K-D, B-K-D, calculate the hypotenuse A-D and B-D, know the total distance A-B, how do I calculate Kx,Ky?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Dijkstra's algorithm a shortest path algorithm. To summarize it,
1-)Add all vertices into a array. 
2-)Select a start vertex.
3-)Create a adjacent array for each vertices that you can know which vertices are adjacent to your starting vertex.(all vertices has key and initially infinity)
4-)Change your adjacent vertex's key to each distance A->B 3,  B's key 3 (
if B.key=A.key+distance < B.key change )
5-)Extract your starting vertex from array,select minimum key,continue with it 6-)until your array will be empty

Comment: Wouldn't Dijkstra's algorithm be finding shortest distance between A, B, C to D rather than the shortest possible point along those routes K, or J? The route is fixed, A to B to C.